# A Python JSONDecodeError:Extra Data

Tags: python, json

I'm a beginner in Python.

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = ('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s/history?p=%s'%(stock_code,stock_code))
r = requests.get(url)
pattern_s = re.compile('"HistoricalPriceStore":{"prices":\[(.*)\],"isPending"')
pattern = re.findall(pattern_s,r.text)
quotes_t = json.loads(pattern[0])
```

when I'm dealing with these code above, something wrong and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-128-ed9fe323f2ef>", line 1, in <module>
    quotes_t = json.loads(pattern[0])

  File "D:\Anaconda\setup\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "D:\Anaconda\setup\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

  JSONDecodeError: Extra data
```

So I change the codes:

```
url = ('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s/history?p=%s'%(stock_code,stock_code))
r = requests.get(url)
pattern_s = re.compile('"HistoricalPriceStore":{"prices":(.*),"isPending"')
pattern = re.findall(pattern_s,r.text)
quotes_t = json.loads(pattern[0])
```

And it execute successfully.
The only difference between them is

```
1.pattern_s = re.compile('"HistoricalPriceStore":{"prices":\[(.*)\],"isPending"')
2.pattern_s = re.compile('"HistoricalPriceStore":{"prices":(.*),"isPending"')
```

Both of them can get the pattern successfully, only with or without '[]'.

1.print the pattern[0] is:

```
[{"date":1518791400,"open":155.7100067138672,"high":157.7899932861328,
"low":155.69000244140625,"close":156.17999267578125,"volume":4239600,
"adjclose":156.17999267578125}...{"date":1487687400,"open":180.60000610351562,
"high":180.7899932861328,"low":179.1199951171875,
"close":180.25999450683594,"volume":4480300,"adjclose":173.1962432861328}]
```

2.print the pattern[0] is:

```
{"date":1518791400,"open":155.7100067138672,"high":157.7899932861328,
"low":155.69000244140625,"close":156.17999267578125,
"volume":4239600,"adjclose":156.17999267578125}...{"date":1487687400,"open":180.60000610351562,"high":180.7899932861328,
"low":179.1199951171875,"close":180.25999450683594,
"volume":4480300,"adjclose":173.1962432861328}
```

Comment: This error indicates that there is something wrong with the JSON you receive (or rather the JSON-like string your regular expression parsing produces) - please provide an example

Comment: url = ('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM/history?p=IBM')
r = requests.get(url)
pattern_s = re.compile('"HistoricalPriceStore":{"prices":\[(.*)\],"isPending"')
pattern = re.findall(pattern_s,r.text)
quotes_t = json.loads(pattern[0])

Comment: I mean provide an example how `pattern[0]` looks like - just print it out and copy paste that into your question (as an [edit], not a comment)

Comment: OK! I will do it immediately. It's the first i use this and i don't know how to do with it. thank you!